# How to install librosa on virtuualenv?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, virtualenv, librosa

I'm trying to install librosa inside virtualenv using python version 3.10.0 and this is what I get. The error is much longer as it keeps trying to install scikit-learn more than once before exiting with error status 1.
I'm not also sure why it's trying to install scikit, but I tried installing scikit-learn first and the same problem happened.

```
Collecting librosa
  Using cached librosa-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (203 kB)
Collecting soundfile>=0.10.2
  Using cached SoundFile-0.10.3.post1-py2.py3.cp26.cp27.cp32.cp33.cp34.cp35.cp36.pp27.pp32.pp33-none-win_amd64.whl (689 kB)
Collecting resampy>=0.2.2
  Using cached resampy-0.2.2.tar.gz (323 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in d:\uni\fall 2021\intro to machine\mlproject\env\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (1.21.4)
Collecting audioread>=2.0.0
  Using cached audioread-2.1.9.tar.gz (377 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting decorator>=3.0.0
  Downloading decorator-5.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.1 kB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.14
  Using cached joblib-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (306 kB)
Collecting pooch>=1.0
  Using cached pooch-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz (6.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2qyais6c'
       cwd: C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p768864v\scikit-learn_76c83a23d0954f8fac85490e461c3618
  Complete output (46 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 319, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 315, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 201, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage("sklearn")
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 85, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p768864v\scikit-learn_76c83a23d0954f8fac85490e461c3618\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 47, in cythonize_extensions      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p768864v\scikit-learn_76c83a23d0954f8fac85490e461c3618\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 113, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p768864v\scikit-learn_76c83a23d0954f8fac85490e461c3618\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 70, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(
    File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-01qr81zy\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/7c/596ff7b32f655f379d3abdfa82607e5cb3b70f46baad4604706511cfeb85/scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=ac2ca9dbb754d61cfe1c83ba8483498ef951d29b93ec09d6f002847f210a99da (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\Scripts\python.exe' 'D:\uni\Fall 2021\intro to machine\MLproject\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Omar\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2qyais6c' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Read the error message. It comes with instructions.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Klaus D. in the comment section, but to provide more details:

At the very bottom of the error message, it says:

```sh
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Python 3.10.0 was released very recently, on October 4, 2021, so more up-to-date visual cpp build tools are required. If 3.10.0 is not a strict requirement, I also suggest downgrading Python version to 3.9 or lower.